# Comma categories of locally finitely presentable categories

Tags: category-theory, locally-presentable-categories, slice-category

Let $\mathbf{C}$ be a locally finitely presentable category, and let $A$ be an object of $\mathbf{C}$. The slice category $\mathbf{C}/A$ is locally finitely presentable. Is this also true for the co-slice category $A/\mathbf{C}$?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, co-slice categories of locally finitely presentable categories are again locally finitely presentable.

More generally, slices and co-slices of λ-presentable categories are again λ-presentable for every regular cardinal λ, as is shown in Proposition 1.57 of Adamek and Rosicky's book "Locally presentable and accessible categories".